# Ubuntu 14.04.3 install DVD hangs after boot on black and white squared screen

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, system-installation, freeze

My younger brother got a desktop with Fedora and Linux Mint on it, but I wanted to install Ubuntu, because it's more user friendly, I heard. It keeps freezing/hanging after the boot screen on a white and black squares screen.

I've been using Ubuntu a lot and never encountered this problem for that long. So, what do I do?

Comment: After the boot it hangs @David Foerster

Comment: possible duplicate of [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

Comment: I couldn't find a related error, but now I see it's a duplicate, but a bit different @David Foerster

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed it myself by using the advanced start up mode and setting the boot parameters to nomodeset with`f6 + down + enter keys`. That way it started up.

It later became known it were errors with a Nvidia legacy card.

And after installation I needed to setup the tested Nvidia legacy drivers. Else I got `4:3` screen resolution